# How to configuration Angular application with routing in IIS?

Tags: angular, iis

I just deploy my application into IIS, but I got a problem with angular routing.
When I access a home routing, it working fine. But when I try to access another routing, it alway return me to home routing.

Below is my config in IIS server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="MyApp Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/MyApp" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Change the line `<action type="Rewrite" url="/MyApp" />` to `<action type="Rewrite" url="/MyApp/" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use below url rewrite rule to resolve this issue:

```
<rules>

  <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">

    <match url=".*" />

    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">

      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />

      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

    </conditions>

    <action type="Rewrite" url="/MyApp/" />

  </rule>

</rules>
```

what is your base url? did you host angular application in iis as application or site?